# Eclipse PHP won't stop at break points

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, xdebug

I'm running Eclipse on `Ubuntu 13.1` (I know, the worst Linux ever).

The fact is that I'm not used to Eclipse moved from Komodo 2 weeks ago, and the main reason why I'd migrated to Eclipse is debugging. But I can't put that to work. I already follow some tutorials with no joy.

My Xdebug is installed and working (checked with `phpinfo()`). I'm configuring Eclipse to work with Xdebug, but when I start the debugging it ignores the break points, even if I check to "Break at First Line" it won't break.

Here's a summary of the scenario that I have:

`System: Ubuntu 13.1 64bits
PHP: 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1
Xdebug: 2.2.3
Eclipse Platform: 3.6.2
PDT: 2.2.1`

Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! Actually the xdebug was installed but I missed one configuration. The xdebug.ini file was with only the following line:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
```

I'd added the following lines:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

and it's working! Just reconfigured the eclipse debug and is working.